# Service account missing from GKE project

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm attempting to add database encryption to a GKE cluster. I had ran a `destroy` on the cluster earlier and I'm now trying to bring it back together.

It feels like a service account should have been created as part of the [private cluster](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/modules/private-cluster) creation.

From my `terraform plan` I'm expecting;

```
  # module.private_cluster.google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member.gke_database_encryption_key will be created
  + resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "gke_database_encryption_key" {
      + crypto_key_id = "projects/my-project/locations/europe-west2/keyRings/prod-keyring/cryptoKeys/prod-gke-encryption-key"
      + etag          = (known after apply)
      + id            = (known after apply)
      + member        = "serviceAccount:service-<project_number>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      + role          = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"
    }
```

But applying this tells me the SA doesn't exist;

```
│ Error: Error applying IAM policy for KMS CryptoKey "projects/my-project/locations/europe-west2/keyRings/prod-keyring/cryptoKeys/prod-gke-encryption-key": 
  Error setting IAM policy for KMS CryptoKey "projects/my-project/locations/europe-west2/keyRings/prod-keyring/cryptoKeys/prod-gke-encryption-key": googleapi: 
  Error 400: Service account service-<project_number>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist., badRequest
│ 
│   with module.private_cluster.google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member.gke_database_encryption_key,
│   on ../../../modules/private_cluster/kms.tf line 18, in resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "gke_database_encryption_key":
│   18: resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "gke_database_encryption_key" {
```

In a previous project with the same resource definition I didn't have this issue, so I assume this SA is meant to be setup as part of the cluster creation. For KMS the resources are defined as;

```
resource "google_kms_crypto_key" "gke_database_encryption_key" {
  name     = var.kms_gke_encryption_key
  key_ring = google_kms_key_ring.kms_keyring.id
  purpose  = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
  # rotation_period = "0s"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "gke_database_encryption_key" {
  crypto_key_id = google_kms_crypto_key.gke_database_encryption_key.id
  role          = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"
  member        = "serviceAccount:service-${var.project_number}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Is it possible to create this SA after the fact, or am I best setting up a new project and starting again?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to recover the `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` default GKE service agent, please take a look into the below doc [1] and [2].

> If you delete the default GKE service agent, you can undelete it by following the instructions in Undeleting a service account.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-accounts#gke-service-agents

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-delete-undelete#undeleting

Comment: Thank you! I had seen docs on disabled SAs, but missed the links off to deleted. Oddly the logs aren't able to find the account that it's looking for when creating resources. So I think I'm going to cut my losses and create a new project.